# Streaming image from AWS S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, stream, filesystems

Image is not always fully stored. The code:

```
const fs = require('fs');
let ws = fs.createWriteStream('/path/blabla.jpg');
aws_s3.getObject(correct_params,function(){}).createReadStream().pipe(ws);
```

This is the result image:
[image: Image streamed from AWS S3]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution I've found:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');
let ws = fs.createWriteStream('/path/blabla.jpg');
request('url-of-file-on-aws-s3').pipe(ws);
```